# Dedicated Services Account and Embedded Sending Experience

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the EnvelopeView: CreateSender endpoint on the server side and are authenticated under a service account we have dedicated for this process. Ultimately, we send a URL such as `https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=<GUID>&DocuEnvelope=<ENVELOPEID>&send=1` back to the end user to pick the signers, and populate tags.

All works fantastically, however, we were hoping to make it so the user can only see and populate the information for this single document. Currently, once the user clicks the link they are essentially authenticated as our backend service account and if they open another tab in their browser and go to (https://demo.docusign.net) they can see all documents and even change the password of the account if they wanted.

Is there a way to restrict this in any way? Would the experience be different if purchased an “API” account not tried to use an actual user account on the backend? Yes, we know about OAuth, but we don’t really want to impersonate the sender and prefer to keep a dedicated service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "API" account would give you the same issues as dedicating one of your current users as a "Services Account," so I don't think that's a solution.

Instead, I suggest that you move all of the functionality that's needed upstream into your app. That way you will not need to present the Sender view to your users.

Your app can enable your users to:

- choose who the envelope will be sent to
- choose/edit the email messages, etc
- choose the documents that will be sent
- etc

If you have preset templates that include the document tabs/fields for the signers then there is no reason for the sender to deal with the sending screen for picking the tab/field locations on the documents.

This type of app will also give a smoother user experience to your users since they'll stay in your app rather than bouncing over to DocuSign for part of the task.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  We do have a scenario that we plan on implementing that could work as you describe, however, in this case we need to present the TAG & SEND screen because we won't have a way to control the template as it is received from a third party.  It sounds like your saying that the TAG & SEND screen and the StartInSession.aspx are only good for when you are ok with the person who receives the link having full access to the account being used including all previously sent documents and even changing the password.  Sigh. :(   Personally, I think our scenario is not uncommon.

Comment: The idea of embedded sending is that you are the sender, not some other user. Why not have the sender be the user? I have submitted DocuSign internal enhancement request. On the other hand, this might be a bug. Have you checked that cookies were cleared before the embedded sending view was used? Maybe the browser had previously logged into the service account.

Comment: Not a bug, you get a session cookie when you click the "...StartInSession.aspx" link.  The docs says the link is a "...one-time use login token that allows the user to be placed into the DocuSign sending view.", which we interpreted as one time for that single tag and send purpose, not one time login into the account.  We want our app to have access to Envelopes it has sent directly, and using delegated "user" permissions raises different security concerns.  Thanks for the help, we will contact DocuSign directly for the same enhancement request.